# SmartArt graphics in LaTeX

Tags: graphics, tikz-arrows

I want to make a SmartArt Graphic (as it is called in PowerPoint) to show different types of convergence and links between these one for measure theory course. I made in LaTeX the following 'SmartArt graphic':
Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\geometry{left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,every node/.style={shape=rectangle,draw,rounded corners},]
    % create the nodes
    \node (c1)[font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ]{
    $\left.
      \begin{array}{c}
        \textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a}} \\
        \textbf{uniform\u{a} aproape sigur\u{a}} \\
      \end{array}
    \right.
    $
     };
    \node (c2) [left =of c1,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {\textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} complet\u{a}}};
    \node (c3) [below =of c2,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {\textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} tare}};
    \node (c4) [below =of c1,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {\textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} aproape sigur\u{a}}};
    \node (c5) [right =of c4,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {\textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} uniform asimptotic\u{a}}};
    \node (c6) [below left =of c4,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {\textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n probabilitate}};
    \node (c7) [below right =of c4,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {
    $\left.
      \begin{array}{c}
        \textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n }\\
        \textbf{medie de ordinul $r>0$} \\
      \end{array}
    \right.
    $
    };
    \node (c12) [below=of c7,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {\textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n $L^q,0<q<r$}};
    \node (c8) [below =of c6,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {\textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n  reparti\c{t}ie}};
    \node (c9) [below =of c8,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {\textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n func\c{t}ie de reparti\c{t}ie}};
    \node (c10) [below =of c9,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont ] {
    $\left.
      \begin{array}{c}
        \textbf{Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n func\c{t}ie}\\
        \textbf{caracteristic\u{a}} \\
      \end{array}
    \right.
    $
    };
    \draw[bend left=45,black,latex-,line width=2pt] (c3.west) to (c2.west);
    \draw[bend left=45,blue,latex-,line width=2pt] (c2.east) to (c3.east);
    \draw[black,latex-,->,line width=2pt] (c4.west) to (c3.east);
    \draw[black,latex-,->,line width=2pt] (c1.south) to (c4.north);
    \draw[black,latex-,<->,line width=2pt] (c5) to (c4);
    \draw[bend left=25,black,latex-,line width=2pt] (c6.north) to (c4.south west);
    \draw[bend left=25,red,latex-,line width=2pt] (c4.south) to (c6.east);
    \draw[bend left=10,red,latex-,line width=2pt] (c4.south east) to (c7.north);
    \draw[bend left=25,blue,latex-,line width=2pt] (c7.west) to (c4.south);
    \draw[black,latex-,->,line width=2pt] (c7) to (c12);
    \draw[bend left=45,black,latex-,line width=2pt] (c8.west) to (c6.west);
    \draw[bend left=45,blue,latex-,line width=2pt] (c6.east) to (c8.east);
    \draw[black,latex-,<->,line width=2pt] (c8) to (c9);
    \draw[black,latex-,<->,line width=2pt] (c9) to (c10);
    \draw[bend left=35,blue,latex-,line width=2pt] (c4.south) to (c8.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
$$
     \draw[black,latex-,->,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (2,0) node at (4,0){Implica\c{t}ie direct\u{a}};
$$
\end{tikzpicture}
\break \break
\begin{tikzpicture}
$$
     \draw[blue,latex-,->,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (2,0) node at (6,0){Implica\c{t}ie \^{i}n condi\c{t}ii suplimentare};
$$
\end{tikzpicture}
\break \break
\begin{tikzpicture}
$$
     \draw[red,latex-,->,line width=2pt] (0,0) -- (2,0) node at (5,0){Implica\c{t}ie pe un sub\c{s}ir};
$$
\end{tikzpicture}
\break \break
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

and I obtained:
[image]

My question is: How is it possible to format my diagram to look like the one below?
[image]

---

Yes, thank you very much and I am sorry for my lack of bravity (cfr). I translate my graphic and hope that it is correct. (I used : Patrick Billingsley, Convergence of Probability Measures and Albert Shiryaev, Probability).[image]

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of re-drawing the connecting lines using different styles? It seems that you've already got the nodes positioned correctly.

Comment: & Straight lines are simpler, if anything, than curves...? Could you maybe say exactly what problem you're having?

Comment: My problems are: with spacing the elements of diagram, the  straight line that intersects one arrow, below the straight line - how is it possible to link the parts of diagram? Inserting text at right/left, for instance Type I of convergences, Type II of convergences, is also another problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not really understanding. If you want things spaced differently you can say, for example, `left=20pt of` or whatever. And you can draw the straight line wherever you like, so why shouldn't it intersect the arrow?

Comment: You might find it easier to use either a matrix of nodes and/or chains to place/connect the nodes, though.

Comment: By the way, `$$` is long deprecated and ought not ever be used with LaTeX. Use `\[...\]` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\geometry{left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=0.75in,bottom=0.75in}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9,transform shape]
    \tikzset{
      every node/.style={draw,rounded corners,font=\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont\bfseries,align=center,on grid,inner sep=8pt},
      node distance=2cm and 9cm,
      every path/.style={line width=2pt,line cap=round}
    }
    \node (c1)[]{
      Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \\
      uniform\u{a} aproape sigur\u{a}
    };
    \node (c2) [left =of c1,] {Convergen\c{t}\u{a} complet\u{a}};
    \node (c3) [below =of c2,] {Convergen\c{t}\u{a} tare};
    \node (c4) [below =of c1,] {Convergen\c{t}\u{a} aproape sigur\u{a}};
    \node (c5) [right =of c4,] {Convergen\c{t}\u{a} uniform asimptotic\u{a}};
    \node (c6) [below left =4cm and 9cm of c4,] {Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n probabilitate};
    \node (c7) [below right =of c4,] {
      Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n \\
      medie de ordinul $r>0$ 
    };
    \node (c12) [below=of c7,] {Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n $L^q,0<q<r$};
    \node (c8) [below =4cm of c6,] {Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n  reparti\c{t}ie};
    \node (c9) [right=of c8,] {Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n func\c{t}ie de reparti\c{t}ie};
    \node (c10) [right =of c9,] {
      Convergen\c{t}\u{a} \^{i}n func\c{t}ie\\
      caracteristic\u{a} 
    };

    \draw
      (c1) edge (c4) 
      (c2) edge (c3)
      (c3) edge (c4)
      (c4) edge (c5)
      (c4) edge (c6)
      (c4) edge (c7)
      (c7) edge (c12)
      (c6) edge (c8)
      (c8) edge (c9)
      (c9) edge (c10)
    ; 

    \coordinate(sep aux)at($(c6)!.5!(c8)$);
    \coordinate(sep)at($(current bounding box.west|-sep aux)+(-2cm,0)$); 
    \coordinate(T1)at($(current bounding box.north west-|sep)!.5!(sep)$);
    \coordinate(T2)at($(current bounding box.south west-|sep)!.5!(sep)$);

    \draw(sep)--(sep-|current bounding box.east);
    \node[anchor=west,draw=none]at(T1){\Huge I};
    \node[anchor=west,draw=none]at(T2){\Huge II};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]